# Why SQLite 3.7.2 is 3 times faster than 3.7.9 on Step operations

Tags: performance, sqlite, delphi, select

I have checked out the 3.7.2 SQLite from http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/sqlite/3.7.2
I also took the latest 3.7.9 from http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3070900.zip

Compiled both with the same Borland C++ Compiler 5.5.1 settings

```
@echo off

set PATH=C:\Borland\Bcc55\Bin;%PATH%

rem Compilation Options
rem http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omitfeatures

set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS=0
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2

set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=0
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED=1
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPILEOPTION_DIAGS=1
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_OMIT_PROGRESS_CALLBACK=1
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_OMIT_UTF16
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1
set extra=%extra% -DSQLITE_OMIT_EXPLAIN

@echo on

bcc32.exe -6 -O2 -c -d -u- -w- %extra% sqlite3.c
pause
```

With 3.7.2 I takes 500ms to execute 25 000 step operations where 3.7.9 takes tree times more time.

The SQL statement is plain

```
select * from Cards
```

where Cards is a table with 16 text and 4 integer columns

Has the SQLite became slower in the recent versions?

Comment: 500ms to just iterate through only 25000 records? I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong. In my tests (using my wrapper) I can iterate 140000 records in just less than 150ms using 3.7.9 version and this is faster than using prior versions. Without some more code it is impossible to guess where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no big difference between those versions, about implementation speed. Latest 3.7.9 is faster.

I think you do not use the same memory manager in your two implementations. I guess your malloc/free external references are not implemented by the same method: your 3.7.2 may be using Delphi FastMM4, whereas 3.7.9 may be using the default Windows or MSCRT heap.